# Проблема подключения к БД Oracle

Tags: oracle, iis

Имеется сервер приложений, где используется IIS и там развернуты веб-службы. К сожалению, сервер приложений развернут на том же сервере, что база данных Oracle. Недавно системный администраторы накатили новый патч безопасности для Oracle 11.2.0.4.180717. После этого, происходит ошибка подключений IIS-служб к серверу БД Oracle:

```
[`OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-1005: null password given; logon  denied]`
```

Строка подключения в `web.config`:

```
connectionString="Data Source=TEST.BASE.RB;User ID=TTR;Password=TTRP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в строку подключения: `Persist Security Info=True`.

Должно получиться:

```
connectionString="Data Source=TEST.BASE.RB;User ID=TTR;Password=TTRP;Persist Security Info=True"
```